# Two OnClick events overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element inside an element, when I click the element underneath I want the slider to open. When I click on the outermost element I want the slider to close.

Unfortunately when I click on the outermost it clicks the underneath element as well. Is there a way to click only on the outermost element ignoring the click on the underneath element? The events are triggered on click and executed with javascript.

I tried with `z-index` but it still captures the underneath element clicked as well, and because the functions are contrary to one another nothing happens.

edit: on a "code is worth 1000 words" tip

```
var $target = $(this).data('pos', i) //give each li an index #
    $target.data('hpaneloffsetw', $target.find('.hpanel:eq(0)').outerWidth()) //get offset width of each .hpanel DIV (config.dimensions.fullw + any DIV padding)
    $target[haccordion.ismobile? "click" : "mouseenter"](function(){
        haccordion.expandli(config.accordionid, this)
        config.$lastexpanded=$(this)
    })

    if (config.collapsecurrent){ //if previous content should be contracted when expanding current
        $('.close').click(function(){
            $target.stop().animate({width:config.paneldimensions.peekw}, config.speed) //contract previous content
        })
        $target.dblclick(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({width:config.paneldimensions.peekw}, config.speed) //contract previous content
        })
    }
```

`Because the code is borrowed`, I don't understand much of it. But basically I want the "`click`" : "`mousteente`r" function to work on click, without interfering with the .close().click

Comment: Code is worth 10000 words, although it sounds like you need to use `event.stopPropagation` on your click handler.

Comment: try Delegate https://api.jquery.com/delegate/?

Comment: try `e.stopPropagation();`.

Comment: @Sandy: howz your comment different from Rory's above?

Comment: sorry didnt notice he said same thing.

Comment: thank you rory and sandy event.stopPropagation(); worked!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like you need to stop the click event bubbling up the DOM to be caught by parent elements. You can use `stopPropagation()` to do this:

```
$('.close').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $target.stop().animate({ width: config.paneldimensions.peekw }, config.speed);
})
$target.dblclick(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).stop().animate({ width: config.paneldimensions.peekw }, config.speed);
})
```

Comment: thanks! this worked, clear explanation as to why this happens and how to solve it

Comment: hmm I know its a few days later, and it works great on chrome but not on firefox, is firefox not supporting stopPropagation() or its just a bit more picky

Comment: Firefox supports `stopPropagation()`. Why is it not working? Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: yes just `"ReferenceError: event is not defined"` on `stopPropagation()` line

Comment: Have you passed `event` into the click handler? Notice the `(e)` part in my example.

Comment: now that you mention it, i have `event.stopPropagation();`, and no when I `ctr-f` for `event` only 1 instance is found. (How come it works on chrome though)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wa5wj/)

```
$("#outer").click(function(){alert("outer clicked")});
$("#inner").click(function(e){
    alert("inner clicked")
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To identify the element you have "really" clicked on, you can try to identify it through accessing the [target property of the jquery-event-object](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

After you identified the target you clicked on, you could [prevent other event handlers from firing](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS specific jquery to point exact element like below, use `>` to point exact child

```
table > tbody > tr > td > input[type='text']
```

like this.