# Repeated function -JS

Tags: javascript

I create a tree with JSON data. Main idea : every node is div and every child div too.   Problem is when i click the child div, on click function works more than 1. How can I fix this problem? Thanks.
Edit: When i try define onclick before append , still problem continues.
This is my make tree function.

```
function setTree(path){


   function Node(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.children = {}; // object
}
   tree = new Node('root');

    path.forEach(function (a) {
    var parts = a.split('--->');
    parts.reduce(function (r, b) {
        if (!r.children[b]) {
            r.children[b] = new Node(b);
           createDiv(r.id,b);
        }
        return r.children[b];
    }, tree);
});
 document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4);
}
```

And this is my create div function.

```
function createDiv(root,name)
    { alert("r ve b  " +root+"   " +name);
      var output = document.getElementById(root);

    if(!document.getElementById(name))
        {
            var ele = document.createElement("div");
            ele.setAttribute("id",name);                  
            ele.setAttribute("class","impact");
            ele.innerHTML="<a><img src='../resources/images/plusIcon.png' border=0 /></a>" + name; //a onclick='clickIcon()'
            output.appendChild(ele);
          ele.onclick = function() {divClick();};
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Solution:

```
 ele.onclick = function(e){
                 e.stopPropagation();
                 divClick(ele.id);
          };};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're layering your `div` elements, and they each have `onclick` events, so you'll call `divClick()` once for each `div` in the tree.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23490220/6382618) to see how to only process the topmost `div` event.

Comment: what if I have another parameter for function?  Is function test (e, parameter2 )  working for e.stopPropagation() ?

Comment: ele.onclick = function(e){
                 e.stopPropagation();
                 divClick(ele.id);
          };};  is workin. Thanks.